# How to set some values in a method after $state.go in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement that after $state.go I need to call a method where I can set some values. For eg:

```
$state.go('rulesEditor.decisionTble');
    setCellValues();
```

I want to call this method after state.go to set some values on this page before it gets loads.

Is there any way in angular to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can listen for $stateChangeSuccess.

Like this

```
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
//do stuff here
});
```